# Condition and round to nearest 30 minutes interval multiple timestamps SQL BIG QUERY

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I use goodle big query. My query includes 2 different timestamps: `start_at` and `end_at`.

The goal of the query is to round these 2 timestamps to the nearest 30 minutes interval, which I manage using this: `TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(start_at, INTERVAL MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_at), 30) MINUTE),MINUTE)` and the same goes for `end_at`.

Events occur (`net_lost_orders`) at each rounded timestamp.

The 2 problems that I encounter are:

First, as long as `start_at` and `end_at` are in the same 30 min. interval, things work well but when it is not the case (for example when `start_at`: 19:15 (nearest 30 min interval is 19:00) / `end_at`: 21:15 (nearest 30 min interval is 21:00), the results are not as expected. Additionally, I do not only need the 2 extreme intervals but all 30 minutes interval between `start_at` and `end_at`(19:00/19:30/20:00/20:30/21:00 in the example).

Secondly, I don't manage to create a condition that allows to show each interval on a separate row. I have tried to `CAST`, `TRUNCATE`,`EXTRACT`the timestamps and to use `CASE WHEN` and to `GROUP BY` without success.

Here's the final part of the query (timestamps rounded excluded):

```
...
-------LOST ORDERS--------

a AS (SELECT created_date, closure, zone_id, city_id, l.interval_start, 
l.net as net_lost_orders, l.starts_at, CAST(DATETIME(l.starts_at, timezone)AS TIMESTAMP) as start_local_time
FROM `XXX`, UNNEST(lost_orders) as l),

b AS (SELECT city_id, city_name, zone_id, zone_name FROM `YYY`),

lost AS (SELECT DISTINCT created_date, closure, zone_name, city_name, start_local_time, 
TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(start_local_time, INTERVAL MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_local_time), 30) MINUTE),MINUTE) AS lost_order_30_interval,
net_lost_orders
FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.city_id=b.city_id AND a.zone_id=b.zone_id AND a.city_id=b.city_id
WHERE zone_name='Atlanta' AND created_date='2021-09-09'
ORDER BY rt ASC),

------PREPARATION CLOSURE START AND END INTERVALS------
  f AS (SELECT
    DISTINCT TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(start_at, INTERVAL MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM start_at), 30) MINUTE),MINUTE) AS start_closure_30_interval,
    TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(end_at, INTERVAL MOD(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM end_at), 30) MINUTE),MINUTE) AS end_closure_30_interval,
    country_code,
    report_date,
    Day,
    CASE
    WHEN Day="Monday" THEN 1
    WHEN Day="Tuesday" THEN 2
    WHEN Day="Wednesday" THEN 3
    WHEN Day="Thursday" THEN 4
    WHEN Day="Friday" THEN 5
    WHEN Day="Saturday" THEN 6
    WHEN Day="Sunday" THEN 7
  END AS Weekday_order,
    report_week,
    city_name,
    events_mod.zone_name,
    closure,
    start_at,
    end_at,
    activation_threshold,
    deactivation_threshold,
    shrinkage_drive_time,
    ROUND(duration/60,2) AS duration,
  FROM events_mod
  WHERE report_date="2021-09-09"
    AND events_mod.zone_name="Atlanta"
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16
    ORDER BY report_date, start_at ASC)

------FINAL TABLE------
SELECT DISTINCT 
start_closure_30_interval,end_closure_30_interval, report_date, Day, Weekday_order, report_week, f.city_name, f.zone_name, closure, 
start_at, end_at, start_time,end_time, activation_threshold, deactivation_threshold, duration, net_lost_orders
FROM f
LEFT JOIN lost ON f.city_name=lost.city_name
  AND f.zone_name=lost.zone_name
  AND f.report_date=lost.created_date
  AND f.start_closure_30_interval=lost.lost_order_30_interval
  AND f.end_closure_30_interval=lost.lost_order_30_interval
  GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
```

Results:
[image: Results]

Expected results:
[image: Expected results]

I would be really grateful if you could help and explain me how to get all the rounded timestamps between `start_at` and `end_at`on separate rows. Thank you in advance. Best, Fabien

Spreadsheet [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1doOtRIa2DWmWVSAehXtFzVCZ07ItgK4fEZrusTjzLuU/edit#gid=0)

[image]

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  For instance, your query mentions two tables.  What are they?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your quick reply. Is this clearer?

Comment: The usual way to do such a thing is to have a table (or generated sequence, but many DBA prefer a table) that lists every date interval as a row, so you literally have a eg table "cal" that is 1 column called "d" that is values `2001-01-01 00:00:00` `2001-01-01 00:30:00` `2001-01-01 01:00:00` `2001-01-01 01:30:00` ... `2099-01-01 23:30:00` - yep, maybe even 1.75 million rows for your "every half hour, for 100 years". Then you just inner join it on `cal.d BETWEEN yourdata.start_date AND yourdata.end_date` - it will cause the rows to multiply, and you use `cal.d` for the date interval

Comment: no, still not clear enough to present the approach i have in mind. i recommend you to provide sample input data and expected result, so we can play with it, please do and I will follow up with solution

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant How do I do this?

Comment: Include just enough code to allow others to reproduce the problem. For help with this, read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant I added a spreadsheet at the bottom. Does it help? Best, Fabien

Answer (score 3):

Consider below approach

```
select intervals, any_value(t).*, sum(Nb_lost_orders) as Nb_lost_orders
from table1 t, 
unnest(generate_timestamp_array(
  timestamp_seconds(div(unix_seconds(starts_at), 1800) * 1800), 
  timestamp_seconds(div(unix_seconds(ends_at), 1800) * 1800), 
  interval 30 minute
)) intervals
left join (
  select Nb_lost_orders, 
     timestamp_seconds(div(unix_seconds(Time_when_the_lost_order_occurred), 1800) * 1800) as intervals
  from Table2
) 
using(intervals) 
group by intervals
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with Table1 as (
  select 'Closure' Event, timestamp '2021-09-09 11:00:00' starts_at, timestamp '2021-09-09 11:45:00' ends_at union all
  select 'Closure', '2021-09-09 12:05:00', '2021-09-09 14:10:00'
), Table2 as (
  select 5 Nb_lost_orders, timestamp '2021-09-09 11:38:00' Time_when_the_lost_order_occurred
)
```

output is

[image]